# How do I Apply an Anonymous Function from a List in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I am learning Scheme. What is wrong with the code below?I  want to write a program that takes the first function from the list and then applies that to a number?

```
    (define num  3)

    ;;I want to do something like this which returns 3
    ((λ (x) x)num)

    ;;but my functions are in a list so this should return3
    ((first '((λ (x) x) (λ (x) (* x x)))) num)
```

Im getting this error for the above code:
*procedure application: expected procedure, given: (λ (x) x); arguments were: 3*

What does it mean when I get these kinds of output?

When  I dont apply anything, I get a nice output.

```
(first '((λ(x) x)(λ(x) (*x x))))
```

returns (λ (x) x)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're quoting, with ' the lambda, so it isn't being evaluated.

If you just feed in (λ (x) x) at the prompt, DrScheme shows you `#<procedure>`, which means it has actually evaluated the lambda, and given you back a closure. By quoting it, you're giving Scheme just a list of symbols.

If you want to put your functions in a list, you can do:

```
((first (list (lambda (x) x) (lambda (x) (* x x)))) num)
```

The quote allows you to produce a list, yes, but one whose contents aren't evaluated. The list function produces a list from all of its arguments, after they've been evaluated.

You could also quasiquote the list, if you like:

```
((first `(,(lambda (x) x) ,(lambda (x) (* x x)))) num)
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the difference between these expressions?

```
> (procedure? (lambda (n) n))
#t
> (procedure? (quote (lambda (n) n)))
#f
> (procedure? '(lambda (n) n))
#f
```

Jay answered it for you but I can't upvote him yet.

Answer (score 2):

(lambda (x) x) isn't a procedure. It's a form that *evaluates* to a procedure. People are a bit loose with terminology and often call the lambda form a procedure as a kind of shorthand.  “Ceci n'est pas une pipe.”

Comment: True, but ultimately useless as an explanation for newbies that are confused by such issues.  Note BTW that since then Racket changed the way it prints values, which results in a clearer error: "... `expected procedure, given: '(λ (x) x)` ..." -- the quote is new.

Comment: When I was a newbie this was exactly the sentence I needed to clear up the confusion, so I wrote it down to help others.  Perhaps it's just "ultimately useless" for everyone but me.

Comment: The thing is that Scheme has some (very intentional!) confusion between code and data, `x` and `'x`, your explanation is correct (as I said) but it is a similar kind of confusion at the meta level, where `x` is data and "the value bound to *x*" is the "code".  For many students, this kind of duality is very confusing, and mostly does not get completely clear until they go through something like the meta-circular evaluator.

Comment: It gets worse, since it's more like “the variable cell bound to x containing the value of x” :P

Comment: Yes, I intentionally avoided the extra indirection that you get when you introduce mutations and locations.